# Jquery Start from Beginning When A Div Reaches The End of Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i was trying to create a automatic horizontal scroll div which keeps on scrolling its elements in an infinite loop. This is what I have achieved so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
            var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
            var clientWidth = $(window).width();
            $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    $(targetElement).scrollLeft(0);
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        };
        animatethis($('.editors-pick-slideshow'), 10000);
    });
```

```css
.editors-pick-slideshow {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.editors-pick-container {
    width: 3150px;
}
.editors-pick-container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
.editors-pick-elements {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 500px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
.pick1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.pick2 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.pick3 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editors-pick-slideshow">
    <div id="editorsPickContainer" class="editors-pick-container">
        <div>
            <div id="group1" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 1</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="group2" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 2</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="group3" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 3</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in above snippet that when the animation reaches the end of the div it starts abruptly from the beginning. What I want to achieve here is when the animation reaches the end it should continue its flow towards the grid 1 element and keep on scrolling smoothly in an infinite manner. I hope what I am saying makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean parameter indicating which direction to scroll toward and negate the parameter each time the animation is complete.

```
function animatethis(targetElement, toEnd, speed) {
    let pos;
    if (toEnd) {
        let scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
        let clientWidth = $(window).width();
        pos = scrollWidth - clientWidth;
    } else {
        pos = 0;
    }
    $(targetElement).animate({
        scrollLeft: pos
    }, {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function() {
            animatethis(targetElement, !toEnd, speed);
        }
    });
}
animatethis($('.editors-pick-slideshow'), true, 10000);
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function animatethis(targetElement, toEnd, speed){
    let pos;
    if(toEnd){
        let scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
        let clientWidth = $(window).width();
      pos = scrollWidth - clientWidth;
    } else {
        pos = 0;
    }
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft:  pos},
                             {
      duration: speed,
      complete: function () {
        animatethis(targetElement, !toEnd, speed);
      }
    });
  }
  animatethis($('.editors-pick-slideshow'), true, 10000);
});
```

```css
.editors-pick-slideshow {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.editors-pick-container {
    width: 3150px;
}
.editors-pick-container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
.editors-pick-elements {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 500px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
.pick1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.pick2 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.pick3 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editors-pick-slideshow">
    <div id="editorsPickContainer" class="editors-pick-container">
        <div>
            <div id="group1" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 1</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="group2" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 2</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="group3" class="editors-pick-elements">
                <div class="pick1">Grid 3</div>
                <div class="pick2">Grid 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have done above is not what I want to achieve, I want the animation to start from beginning without actually traversing back ... Just like an infinite scroll but in forward direction only. Meaning is it shouldn't stop when it reaches the end rather it should continue with the forward scroll by appending the first grid elements.

Comment: for example check out the top slideshow in this theme: http://pennews.pencidesign.com/  ... notice how it keeps on scrolling in an infinite manner ... I want to achieve something like this.